# numpy unique strange behaviour

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, numerical

according to the official numpy.unique documentation (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) return_index=True should allow me to recover the first occurrences of elements in an array. However, this does not work for this simple example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,3,2,4,3,2,5,2,1,999,1000])
a = np.append(a,np.repeat(999,10000))
u, indices = np.unique(a, return_index=True)
print indices[13], u[13] #according to unique documentation indices[13] should be 16 (i.e. first occurrence of 999 = u[13]), but it is not
```

This results in:

```
[mvogelsberger@itc021 ~]$ python test.py 
6685 999
```

Clearly, 6685 is not the index of first occurrence of 999 in the array a. Can someone clarify? I probably misunderstand the documentation...

Thanks!
Mark

Comment: Your code prints `16 999` for me.

Comment: OK, that is interesting. Which numpy/Python version?

Comment: *Python 2.7.5* + *Numpy 1.7.1*

Comment: OK, i used Numpy 1.6.0, Python 2.7.1. Just changed numpy version and got the correct result. So this must be some bug in Numpy

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2083) and [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2655) numpy bug reports. It all boils down to not using a stable sort (mergesort) when the return indices are needed.

Answer (score 2):

As you've guessed in the comments, this behaviour is indeed [a bug that was fixed in Numpy v1.7](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/dbf235169ed3386b359caaa9217f5280bf1d6749)